# How to catch input radio value before it's changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use radio buttons to select a content type in a form

```html
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="file" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="audio" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="video" />
```

**I would like something along the lines of the following code**

```js
$scope.$watch('type', function(type, previousType) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the type?'))
        $scope.type = previousType;
});
```

Obviously, this code triggers an infinite loop, as the `$scope.type = previousType` line triggers the watcher. Or something like this:

```js
var ignore = false;
$scope.$watch('type', function(type, previousType) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the type?') && !ignore) {
        ignore = true;
        $scope.type = previousType;
        ignore = false;
    }
});
```

But this one would trigger a race condition and `ignore` would be reset to `false` before the watcher triggers.

I also tried storing the `ng-model` value inside a temporary variable, watching this variable, and set `ng-selected="type == 'file'"` (and so on) on the radio buttons, but it doesn't work either.

**Is there an elegant way to intercept the value and test it before the actual `ng-model` gets updated?**

Comment: Why not use ng-change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` to accomplish this:

`<input ng-click="changed()" type="radio" ng-model="my.type" value="file" />`

```
var lastVal = false;
$scope.changed = function(){
  if (lastVal !== false && $scope.my.type != lastVal){
    if (!confirm('are you sure?')) {
        $scope.my.type = lastVal;
      return;
    }
  }
  lastVal = $scope.my.type;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aws7uLwr/

Note: This will fire any watchers on those elements which may or may not matter based on your implementation.

EDIT: Alternate answer referenced in comments:

```
var ignore = false;
$scope.$watch('type', function(type, previousType) {
  if (ignore){
    ignore = false;
    return;
  }
  if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the type?')) {
    ignore = true;
    $scope.type = previousType;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your first answer (before you edited it) did the trick, thank you! I will accept your post though. The `ng-click` stuff might work but in my case, the whole label-input is clickable so I don't think it's the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with the exact syntax (ng stuff), but try to "unbind" the watch just before the `$scope.type = previousType;`, and immediately after that line, re-bind the `.$watch` thingie...

That way, when you reset the `.type`, it won't trigger the "watcher", and you can easily avoid the infinite loop, and the need of the redundant "flag" (`ignore` in your code).

Comment: Yup, the correct answer has been posted yesterday but has disappeared. It was along the lines of my second attempt (an `ignore` flag), I just didn't implemented it well. It works now.